# url-masking redirect http to https using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-mapping, url-masking

I have created url-masking (url-mapping) on my portal. 
Same php code are running with different urls.
My portal link is http://subdomain.domain.in (main-link) and client url is http://www.client-domain.com.
I want to redirect client URL HTTP to https using my .htaccess file.

Edit from comment:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^client-domain.in [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.in [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Please provide your current attempts.

Comment: This is my .htaccess code,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved now. 
I have added this code in .htaccess, and client's url work with HTTPS.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.client-domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-domain.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can use below code for the same

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

it will redirect your url http to https.

Comment: I have tried this code, but both links are open with HTTPS . I want to redirect only client url HTTP to HTTPS.